# Duda en python, guia que estoy intentando completar

Tags: python, bucle-for, while, visual, studio

Escribir un programa que añada valores a una lista mientras que su longitud sea menor a 120 y luego mostrar la lista "usar while y for"

Tengo que hacer este ejercicio y la verdad que no se por donde empezar ni siquiera, por favor alguien podría ayudarme? no entiendo muy bien lo de while y for, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Mira no te voy a resolver la tarea, pero explicaré toda la lógica para que tu puedas hacerlo.

tanto un `for` como un `while` son *ciclos* o *loops* es decir un proceso que se repite n veces, en este proceso se va a ejecutar un bloque de código determinado, pero estos ciclos reciben unas sentencias para que puedan ser ejecutados.

El ciclo `while` ejecuta un bloque de código **mientras** la condición o sentencia se cumpla, un ejemplo común `while True:`, esto es un ciclo infinito, pues `True` siempre será `True`.

El ciclo `for` mayormente se usa para recorrer o hacer un proceso determinado en una estructura de datos como las listas `[]`, ejemplo `for i in [1,2,3,4]`. Este ciclo es mucho mas interesante pues admite diversas *variaciones* como un `for in ..`, `for in range()`, `for (0,1) in`. También están las *list comprehension* o *comprensiones de lista*.

**Sintaxis de un ciclo `for`**

```py
for i in iterable:
    #code
    pass
```

Los ciclos `for` son solo validos para objetos iterable, por eso decía que se usan para *iterar* en estructuras de datos (listas, tuplas, diccionarios, strings). La variable `i` es llamada *variable de control* ya que de acuerdo a esta se repetirá el ciclo, en Python no es necesario hacer `i++` pues Python repetirá el ciclo según el tamaño del iterable.

Si nosotros queremos iterar en una lista y obtener cada valor nos bastaría con implementar el ejemplo anterior.

```py
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
   #i tomara el valor de cada elemento de la lista
   print(i) #imprimimos el valor de i
```

**salida**

```
1
2
3
4
```

Otro ejemplo muy común es utilizar la función `range()` para hacer que el ciclo se repita *n* veces según el rango de números que le pasemos, donde la *variable de control* tomará el valor del número.

```py
for i in range(2,5): se repite desde el 2 hasta el 4
    #el end se utiliza para indicar como terminará la impresion
    print(i, end=" ")  #por defecto es un salto de linea pero cambiamos este valor
```

**salida**

```
2 3 4
```

El ciclo `while` te puede servir para repetir un proceso n veces, esto es útil si no sabes cuanta veces lo vas a repetir, por ejemplo si pides un dato al usuario. Este ciclo tiene unas sentencias `break` (rompe el ciclo), `continue` (vuelve al principio) y `pass` (no hace nada :/)

**ejemplo**

Aqui vamos a pedirle datos al usuario hasta que ponga `0`

```py
while True: #se ejecutara siempre
    valor = input("ingrese un dato: ") #pedimos un dato
    valor = int(valor) #convertimos a entero
    print("el valor fue ", valor) #imprimimos
    if valor == 0: #comprobamos si es 0
        break #rompemos el ciclo
```

Y así podemos repetir un proceso las veces que queramos. Le puede poner cualquier condición al `while` (siempre que pueda ser evaluada en booleano), por ejemplo.

```py
valor = 0 #declaramos antes la variable, si no nos dara error de referencia
while valor !=0:
    valor = input("ingrese un dato: ") #pedimos un dato
    valor = int(valor) #convertimos a entero
    print("el valor fue ", valor) #imprimimos
```

Aquí ya no necesitamos usar el `if` ya que al terminar el ciclo este volverá a evaluar la condición, en este caso `valor !=0`, y si el resultado es `True` volverá a ejecutar el código que tiene adentro y como estamos reemplazando el valor de la variable `valor` no hay problema, ya que al volverla a evaluar esta tendrá el valor que se le haya asignado. En resumen en cada repetición se evalúa la expresión dada.

reo que con esta explicación ya podrás resolver tu tarea, además no hace mal hacer una búsqueda en internet :D

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude hacerlo, era relativamente simple pero no lograba entender, y perdon si parecia que queria que me hicieran la tarea jasdja :( la verdad es que me atrase algunas clases, con tu explicacion pude entenderlo facil, me quedo asi